# Getting httpContext.User.Identity.Name when running ASP.NET Core in project mode and not IIS Express

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I normally run my ASP.NET Core project using IIS Express and with that I can get `httpContext.User.Identity.Name as I have Windows Authentication enabled for IIS Express`, but now I want to run my web app in project mode so that I can see the debug console window and view all logging, but now `httpContext.User.Identity.Name` is `NULL`.

How can I get `httpContext.User.Identity.Name` populated when running my web app as a project as shown below and not in IIS Express?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to use windows authentication?

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that. In IIS Express it works perfectly because I have enabled Windows Authentication but running my application as the project returns NULL

Answer (score 0):

Install nuget package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate`.

Then in your `Program.cs` add:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;
// ...

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

// ...

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

// ...

app.Run();
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#kestrel)